# customizing hibernate properties in hyperjaxb

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb, hyperjaxb

The default configuration of `hyperjaxb` is creating hibernate annotations that result in `hibernate` annotations that produce incredibly verbose `SQL` statements that result in `SQLException`s at worst and slow performance at best.  Specifically, the `CascadeType.ALL` setting seems to be the default.  How do I override the default settings so that `CascadeType`, `FetchType`, and other parameters are set on a customized basis?  And is it possible to set these default variables on a global level so that I do not have to change every one of many hundreds of references in my schema.xsd file?

Here is an example.  `Hyperjaxb` is generating the following `hibernate` annotation:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Code.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinColumn(name = "SOME_CODE1_P_0")
public Code getSomeCode1() {
    return someCode1;
}
```

from the following schema fragment:

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeTypeName">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="someCode1" type="Code" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="someCode2" type="Code" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="someCode3" type="Code" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="someCode4" type="Code" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="someCode5" type="Code" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Code">
    <!--<xs:sequence>elements with nested data types omitted for simplicity</xs:sequence>-->
    <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" use="optional"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="optional"></xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize default mappings as you want:

http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Customizing+default+mappings

Here are the [default customizations](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/plugin/src/main/resources/org/jvnet/hyperjaxb3/ejb/strategy/customizing/impl/DefaultCustomizations.xml).

And here's a test project which [customizes defaults](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/cu-one/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb).

For instance, customizing the default cascade for `many-to-one` would look like (untested):

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <hj:persistence>
        <hj:default-many-to-one>
            <!-- So what do you think to be a reasonable default mapping? -->
            <orm:cascade>
                <orm:cascade-persist/>
            </orm:cascade>
        </hj:default-many-to-one>
    </hj:persistence>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Further links:

- [Customizations schema](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/schemas/customizations/src/main/resources/customizations.xsd)
- [Customizations guide](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Customization+Guide)

Please check the documentation. You can (but don't have to) customize *a lot*.

Comment: Thank you.  What about `fetchType`?

Comment: Anything: https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/schemas/customizations/src/main/resources/orm/orm_1_0.xsd#L1198

Comment: Thank you. Your link implies that one adds a `simpleType` `fetch-type` to the `xsd` file and then adds a `fetch attribute` to every `complexType`.  Is there a way to set it as a global setting rather than in several hundred locations?  And what about a resulting entity that needs to have `fetchtype=lazy` when used as a property in some classes but `fetchtype=eager` when used as a property in other classes?

Comment: @CodeMed You can customize globally (default mappings) as well as locally (specifices per complex type or property). Please read the customization guide I linked to.